# Getting Tweepy in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to install Tweepy on PyCharm. I have the latest version of PyCharm, and I am attempting to clone tweepy from GitHub. I have tried running the code in PyCharm, IDLE, and the python interpreter in the Mac Terminal. None have worked, and any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What have you done in your attempts?  Feeding the github clone address https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git into pycharm's "check out from version control" screen works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 4):

for installing tweepy in pycharm:

1. press **ALT** + **F12** to open the **Terminal**
2. type: **pip install tweepy**

Answer (score 1):

I have PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.5 and I successfully added tweepy on PyCharm. Here are the steps: Go to *PyCharm* -> *Preferences* -> *Project: your_project* -> *Project Interpreter*, then on the bottom of the window clic the "**plus**" button and type tweepy. Select tweepy on the left side of the window and click the **Install Package** button. Once you have installed it, then press **OK** button. Done !
Good luck

-Mauricio

Answer (score 0):

Your best choice will be the terminal route along with the IDE installation. I always have this issues with windows machines.

Seems like using both methods completes a "Symlink" of some sort.